# Make adobe Photoshop CC color picker palette bigger

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, palette

I'm having trouble with picking and testing colors on the image because the color palette is too small for my laptop display. 
Is there a way I can make color palette's window bigger?

[image]

Thanks, Ričards.

Comment: Your questions reads "color palette" but your image has an arrow pointing to the **color picker**, which is it you are referring to?? The image shows *both* the picker and the Swatches panel....

Comment: Actually.. the image shows the color picker (can not be resized) and the Stroke Options for a shape (can be resized).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative option is to open the color panel, Window -> Color.

The panel can be size to your liking but it is not convenient to change how you pick a color (HSL, Lab, Hex, Etc). To bring that up you have to select that from dropdown (3-line icon).

Answer (score 0):

Just slowly hover your mouse cursor over the panel's **borders** until you see a double-headed arrow, click, hold and drag. I hope this will help if you are using **Photoshop CC**. Because earlier versions like CS6 will not support this method.

Comment: Interesting.. this doesn't work in my CC2017/Mac version at all. There's no way to resize the color picker, other than reducing your monitor's resolution.

Comment: I'm using CC 2017 too and this doesn't work. https://i.gyazo.com/891aa15da398ac7b05bb8a5438f901cf.gif

Comment: I think there's a bit of confusion here. That works for the Swatches panel, not for the Color Picker.